# Ajax response parsing & load javascript files

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
ajaxurl = "returnJsonData.php"
data = {'a':blabla,'b':basdasd,'c':aserer,'d':tyrty,'e':fdfg,'f':qwewqe}

function includeJsFile(jsFileName)
{
    //var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = jsFileName;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    document.head.appendChild(script);
}


  $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        var resp = $.parseJSON(response);

        drawChart(
```

bla bla
                    );
        });

The problem I have is that localArr[0] contains the name of the property object to clone say for example, `"colGraphProps"`. This variable is defined in 
`"propsFile.js"` which I'm tryingg to load earlier in this question. The problem is that  $localArr[0] is enclosed within double quotes as part of json response & hence the actual variable value isn't being substituted. How can I overcome this? I'm also not sure if the includeJsFile function is loading the JS files ( I don't see an error during the operation)

The PHP file basically executes a database query & returns the output

**returnJsonData.php**

```
   bla bala bala code

    if ($result) {
    $ajaxResp = [
  bla bla
    ];
    echo  json_encode($ajaxResp);
    }
```

Happy to change the way I do things if the situations warrants. I look forward to some help please.

Comment: Loading a pure JSON response as the contents of a `<script>` tag won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `eval(<<requied_property_in_double_quote>>)` did the trick. Also, using `includeJsFile(filename)`, I was able to load the javascript. One can use eval as appropriate to interpret the values.